# Implementing an Interstitial Ad using AdMob in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, admob, ads, interstitial

I'm in process of making 2D game for Android using Unity and C#.
My banner Ad is glitching. I explained it better in this image.
[image]
I'm facing trouble with Interstitial Ad not showing up at all.
I want it to show up after 3 deaths.
You can see my code below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;a

public class Ad3 : MonoBehaviour
{
    private BannerView bannerView;                              // Banner Ad
    public InterstitialAd interstitial;                         // Interstitial Ad
    static int loadCount = 0;                                   // Interstitial Ad

    public void Awake()
    {
        MobileAds.Initialize(initStatus => { });                // Initializing Ad SDK
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        this.RequestBanner();                                   // Show Banner AD in the Start
        if (loadCount % 3 == 0)                                 // Interstitial Ad - only show ad every third death - Got this line from another stackoverflow question - so, is loadCount universal?
        {
            this.ShowInterstitial();
        }
        loadCount++;
    }
    
    public void RequestBanner()
    {
        string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111";
        this.bannerView = new BannerView(adUnitId, AdSize.Banner, AdPosition.Top);

        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();    // Create an empty ad request.
        this.bannerView.LoadAd(request);                        // Load the banner with the request.
    }
    
    public void RequestInterstitial()                                   // Interstitial Ad
    {
        string InterstitialAdID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712";
        this.interstitial = new InterstitialAd(InterstitialAdID);       // Initialize an InterstitialAd.
        
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();            // Create an empty ad request.
        this.interstitial.LoadAd(request);                              // Load the interstitial with the request.
    }
    public void ShowInterstitial()                                   // Interstitial Ad
    {
        if (this.interstitial.IsLoaded())
        {
            this.interstitial.Show();
        }  
    }

}
```

Appreciate all your feedback.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you never call "RequestInterstitial()" anywhere
Need to request the interstitial to be able to show
Note: Check if the times to show the ad in another script and that script will call the function to show interstitial:

`SingletonTest.Instance.TheFunctionThatShowInsterstitial();`

Example of Singleton:

```
 public class SingletonTest : MonoBehaviour
 {
   public static SingletonTest Instance;

   private void Awake()
   {
     if (Instance == null)
     {
         Instance = this;
         
     }
     else if(Instance != this)
     {
         Destroy(gameObject);
         return;
     }
     DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
   }
}
```

Comment: Oh right. That was dumb lol. Will try now. Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: I called it at start. Still hasn't showed up :/ `this.RequestInterstitial();`

Comment: if you request the instertitial and want to show at the same time will not show anythging because have hight chances of not be loaded yet. Everytime that you enter in that scene will reload the start again so the insterstitial will be empty again has to load the request.
My recomendation is use a Singleton pattern and use and DontDestroyOnLoad object.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. The problem is I don't know how to implement it due to my lack of knowledge in coding. I have created an Ad Manager (in Hierarchy) and attached the Ads script to it. I made the RequestInterstitial and the DontDestroyOnLoad at Awake. And at Start, I added ShowInterstitial if loadCount is 3. I watched many YouTube videos and read many guides, still didn't get it. The thing is -as you know- everyone has their way of coding, which is different than mine. It's not 1+1=2. Updated script: https://pastebin.com/2TLha7KW

Comment: I really appreciate your support. While comparing the code in your first reply, I had previously set the exact 'instance' lines in GameControl.cs Awake() script, except for DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);..... I'm guessing, C# only allows one instance? If so, then this might not work :/

Comment: That is because is an static variable so when you refer to that variable you want to have only one script. if you have more than that script your are not sure about what script are you referencing. Thats the way wich i choose to work, but you can do it in diferent ways